Como compilar un App de Astro con el archivo .env de desarrollo
Tengo un app en Astro y necesito poder compilar pero que use las variables del archivo .env.development ya que va a un servidor dev y no producción he intentado modificar el archivo package.json asi
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "astro dev",
    "start": "astro dev",
    "build": "astro check && astro build --mode development",
    "preview": "astro preview",
    "astro": "astro"
  },

Tampoco funciona si uso
"build": "astro check && astro build --env=development"

Pero no funciona, siempre usando npm run build toma las variables del archivo env.production, como puedo hacer para escoger el archivo que quiero que use
